# How to pass StringVar flag into http.Get

Tags: html, go, get

I'm trying to write some code that checks http status codes from websites. I want users to be able to put custom urls.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var svar string
    flag.StringVar(&svar, "url", "google.com", "a url to check needs to be inputed here")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println("Welcome to the NVIDIA API Checker v0.4 by redstone2019.")
    fmt.Println("This will loop forever giving HTTP Status Codes.")
    fmt.Println("Please wait. (Usually takes aroung 10-30 seconds per loop)")
    for {
        resp, err := http.Get(&svar)
        now := time.Now()
        // Print the HTTP Status Code and Status Name
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(now)
        fmt.Println("HTTP Response Status:", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

That is my current code, but it says
`cannot use &svar (type *string) as type string in argument to http.Get`

Comment: `svar` is a `string`, and doing `&svar` will give you a pointer to `svar`, i.e. `*string`. As you can see in the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Get), you should be passing a `string`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to GoLang and I tried to research this, but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: `http.Get(svar)`

Comment: Please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) - it only takes a few minutes and should help you with these kinds of basic language questions.

Answer (score 1):

I can thoroughly recommend the section on pointers here, which has helped me as I learn GO and write my own API functions https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

as Emile says, read through the http get function docs, and this pointer doc, and you will fix the problem!

Good luck

Comment: Yeah, it works thanks for the help. I'll make sure to check out that tutorial.